# itemstyle.xsl image styling

Tags: xslt

I'm using the itemstyle.xsl file to format a CQWP query on a page.  Everything is working except that I want to fix the height and width of an image.  I'm displaying the image with :

```
<xsl:value-of select="@PublishingPageImage" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

The output of this line is :

```
<img style="BORDER: 0px solid; " src="/SiteCollectionImages/theImage.gif" alt="">
```

Is there a way to set the width and height of the image on ?  I'm not a big xslt expert... I couldn't find any example.

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

In your XSLT when you render the Image you can add attributes to that element.

Example:

```
<img src="{$ImageUrl}" title="blah" alt="blah">
    <xsl:attribute name="height">90px</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="width">150px</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Hope this helps :)